# CKEditor image plugin configuration

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I really need to get rid of these properties in image plugin, I need only allow users to set src, that's all, but I can't figure out how is that done, because javascript and ckeditor is not my strong side. Does anyone knows?

I'm using CKEditor 4.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="editor" name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
        // interested in (the 'image' dialog).
        if (dialogName == 'image') {
            // Get a reference to the 'Image Info' tab.
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
            // Remove unnecessary widgets/elements from the 'Image Info' tab.
            infoTab.remove('browse');
            infoTab.remove('txtHSpace');
            infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');
            infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
            infoTab.remove('txtAlt');
            infoTab.remove('txtWidth');
            infoTab.remove('txtHeight');
            infoTab.remove('htmlPreview');
            infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');
            infoTab.remove('ratioLock');
        }
    });
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
</script>
```

Comment: Does that work? Usually the image dialog depended on the existance of some fields and if you try to remove them then it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yes, it does work. These are additional configuration fields when not present does not break the image plugin.

Comment: It's great that they have fixed that because as I said it used to break the plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307967/remove-htmlpreview-in-ckeditors-image-plugin

Comment: Was not aware this was breaking earlier. Thanks for information.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use ckfinder to browse the images.
here is the code to use when you call coeditor:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        // This call can be placed at any point after the
        // <textarea>, or inside a <head><script> in a
        // window.onload event handler.

CKEDITOR.replace('testoEditor', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../../ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../../ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images',
    width : '505',
    height : '400',

});

//]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: You didn't understand me. Files will not be uploaded, I need users only allow to set img[src] for example: www.imagehost.com/image1.png. I do not need file manager, and it's not for admin panel, it's for all users, and I do not want them to set borders to image and that kind of unnecessary things

Comment: Exactly, because ckeditor doesn't upload files, you need an external script doing that, you can incorporate ckfinder to browse the images

Comment: I do not want them to upload any file, just to set EXTERNAL link to image, thats all

Comment: I need the same plugin -> image, but only get rid of those things I crossed out